# After updating flutter to flutter 1.0.0, I have got error in gradle when running a project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Following is the problem. I have tried several propositions in forum by any solutions. Please help!

Launching lib\main.dart on 9022X in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:

```
ProcessException: Process "C:\src\vscode\lenni\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:common:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1 > com.android.tools:repository:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-alpha10

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:6.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/6.0/asm-analysis-6.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-alpha10

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-alpha10

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/6.0/asm-util-6.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:6.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:common:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:23.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-alpha10

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.1

      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.5.0

      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'.

            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

   > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.

     Required by:

         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.5.0

      > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.pom'.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 8s
  Command: C:\src\vscode\lenni\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I have tried updating gradle-wrapper.properties to disdistributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip, putting mavenCentral() and maven {url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'} in buildscript inside build.gradle,

Comment: I have seen it but don't understand how to do with.

Comment: Are you using some plugins?

Comment: Yes! They are : ' path_provider: ^0.4.1', 
  'shared_preferences: ^0.4.3', 
  'auto_size_text: ^0.2.2', 
  'numberpicker: ^0.1.7',
  'sqflite: ^0.12.2+1'
  pref_dessert: ^0.2.3

Comment: Did you put code on manifest that plugin says you have to?